# Microphone audio from JS in Python

Tags: javascript, python, webm

I am recording microphone input on website and sending this audio to backend:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
.then(stream => {
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
  mediaRecorder.start();

  const audioChunks = [];
  mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
    audioChunks.push(event.data);
  });

  mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
    const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('speech', audioBlob, 'command');

    axios.post('/command', data)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
});
```

On my backend (running on Flask), I have a problem with opening (or accessing) it. When I use `wave` module:

```
audio = request.files['speech']
audio.save(audio.filename)

with wave.open(audio.filename, 'r') as speech:
  # Do something ...
  return jsonify({
    'status': "OK",
  })
```

I'll end up with error message `wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id`. How to solve this? Should I convert it to something else (audio seems to be WebM format)? What is proper way, how to handle microphone audio from website in Python?

Comment: Add a RIFF id to the front of the wave file.  http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

Comment: @RobertHarvey is there any Python library for that, or do I have to do it manually? Not experienced in direct editing of files and headers...